# Long polling using node.js to get database updates

Tags: mysql, node.js, long-polling

I'm fairly new to Node JS,As I switched from java server pages to node mainly to implement server push technology.

I want to implement a simple application, Which will push the data to users if any new record insertion in Mysql database taken place.

And take database name as wst and table name is registered_people,Table consists of one column named users.

Know if any record is inserted into table it should notify that a new user is added to current users.

How can I achieve that.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

This is what libraries like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) were designed for. It makes server push operations trivial.

As far as how to actually trigger the server push, that can be more complicated based on how you're getting the data into the database. If all the data into and out of the mysql database goes through the same node application, it's fairly straightforward. Just raise an event when there is an insert into the table, and have your socket.io (or other push code) listen for those events. Then every time a user it added, the message gets sent.

If the database is updated from multiple applications things get a bit more tricky. You can poll the database for updates to the user table, and then fetch the latest users when it changes. You could do something like the following:

```
setInterval(function() {
  getUserCount(function(userCount) {
    if(userCount > originalUserCount) {
      //  We have new users!
      //  Get the latest user and send it to the connected browsers.
    } 
  });
}, 1000);
```

This isn't very efficient, but doing a `SELECT COUNT(id) FROM Users;` shouldn't add much overhead to your database. A cleaner solution would be to use some sort of messaging queue. If you have multiple systems interacting on a single database, a messaging system can ensure that you give all of those systems a chance to subscribe to things that are happening in other parts of the system. In this case you can have your node app subscribe to new user messages in the system and send them to the browsers.

Answer (score 2):

http://socket.io/ is what you are looking for.

As shown in he documentation, its very simple to listen on server using socket.io

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

And connect to it using,

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
});
```

You could achieve push by broadcasting the update to all connected clients using `io.sockets.emit(object);` whenever your database state is changed.

Its also possible to restrict the message to a specific set of clients by using [rooms](https://gist.github.com/crabasa/2896891)